# Grails - g:textField creates two auto fill results in Firefox

Tags: grails, gsp

I'm creating a g:form and using `<g:textField name="fieldName" value="fieldValue" />`. When a Firefox user submits the form and comes back to it, the user can start typing in "fieldName" and will see it appear twice in the auto fill dropdown list. Is there a way to make it only appear once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is a bug with firefox version 23 which is yet to be fixed. I think there is a way to disable autofilling of text fields but that would disable them for all pages in firefox.

See further information here:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/969138

Comment: To add to your post, your link shows the bug is getting fixed in version 26, which will be released next week.